# How to create torch.tensor object and to update only some of its elements?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, gradient-descent

Let's say I want to create torch.tensor object of size [2,3] filled with random elements, and I intend to use this matrix in the network and optimize it's values. However, I want to update only some of the the values in the matrix.

I know that it can be done for a tensor by setting up parameter `requires_grad` To `True` or `False`. However, the following code

```
z = torch.rand([2,3], requires_grad=True)
z[-1][-1].requires_grad=False
```

does not work as expected

```
RuntimeError: you can only change requires_grad flags of leaf variables. If you want to use a computed variable in a subgraph that doesn't require differentiation use var_no_grad = var.detach().
```

How to fix this RuntimeError? How to initialize torch tensor and then define which elements there would have `requires_grad =True`?

If I write code in a similar manner:

```
z = torch.rand([2,3], requires_grad=False)
z[-1][-1].requires_grad=True
```

There will be no error, but no change of the requires_grad as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not really make much sense to have a *single* tensor which `requires_grad` for only part of its entries.
Why not have two *separate* tensors one that us updated (`requires_grad=True`) and another one fixed (`requires_grad=False`)? You can then merge them for computational ease:

```py
fixed = torch.rand([2, 3], require_grad=False)
upd = torch.rand([2, 3], require_grad=True)
mask = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]], require_grad=False)  # how to combine the two
# combine them using fixed "mask":
z = mask * fixed + (1-mask) * upd
```

You can obviously have other methods of combining `fixed` and `upd` other than using a binary `mask`.
For example, if `upd` occupies the first two columns of `z` and `fixed` the rest, then:

```py
fixed = torch.rand([2, 1], require_grad=False)
upd = torch.rand([2, 2], require_grad=True)
# combine them using concatination
z = torch.cat((upd, fixed),dim=1)
```

Or, if you know the indices

```py
fidx = torch.tensor([0, 2], dtype=torch.long)
uidx = torch.tensor([1, 3, 4, 5], dtype=torch.long)
fixed = torch.rand([2,], require_grad=False)
upd = torch.rand([4,], require_grad=True)
z = torch.empty([2, 3])
z[fidx] = fixed 
z[uidx] = upd
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try your idea and the following code.

`fixed = torch.rand([2, 3]) 
upd = torch.from_numpy(fixed.data.numpy())
upd.require_grad = True
mask = torch.tensor([[0., 1., 0.], [1, 0., 1.]])
z = mask * fixed + (1-mask) * upd`

My worry is that I am making unnecessary calculations. It is not a big deal in this example for [2,3] tensor, but will be a big deal if there will be over a million elements. Besides, ideologically I don't even need this mask, I know the indexes of the elements that should not be updated. What are the other methods you mentioned?

Comment: @user48115 if your "masked" elements follow a specific pattern, you might have `fixed` and `upd` as smaller tensors, and `z` is created by concatenating them. please see my update.