# Can I create an Upper triangular tensor in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to create an upper triangular tensor in `pytorch` which I want that the lower half of the upper triangular tensor constant zeros. And the lower half of the upper triangular tensor have no grad.
When I use `torch.triu()` to get upper triangular tensor, the lower half of the upper triangular tensor have grad which means that such "zeros" are not constant.
So how to get an upper triangular tensor and let the lower half of the upper triangular tensor constant zeros?

```
import torch
a=torch.randn(5,5)
c=torch.randn(1,5)
b=torch.triu(a).requires_grad_()
loss=torch.matmul(c,b)
loss=loss.sum()
loss.backward()
print(b.grad)
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

It does appear that `torch.triu()` gives you an upper triangular matrix and the gradients appear to be correct.

For example, lets say that

```py
x = torch.randn(5, 5, requires_grad=True)
```

produces

```
tensor([[ 0.1907, -0.0990,  1.0373,  0.3676, -0.2752],
        [ 1.8987,  1.0265, -0.1133,  0.1476, -3.5617],
        [ 1.2581,  0.2860, -1.9215, -0.7674, -0.1687],
        [ 0.1559, -0.9870, -0.6928,  0.1487,  0.3346],
        [ 0.6317, -0.4915,  1.2506,  0.8678,  0.6367]], requires_grad=True)
```

Then we can take the upper triangular part of `x` using

```py
y = torch.triu(x)
```

and `y` will then be

```py
tensor([[ 0.1907, -0.0990,  1.0373,  0.3676, -0.2752],
        [ 0.0000,  1.0265, -0.1133,  0.1476, -3.5617],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000, -1.9215, -0.7674, -0.1687],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.1487,  0.3346],
        [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.6367]], grad_fn=<TriuBackward>)
```

The claim that "the lower half of the upper triangular tensor have grad which means that such zeros are not constant" indicates there may be a little confusion about what is expected of the gradients here.

**The only implication as far as gradients are concerned is that no matter what we do with `y`, the lower part of `x` will not have any impact on the final result since it has been effectively multiplied by a constant zero. Therefore the derivative of any function resulting from `y` with respect to any of the lower components of `x` will be zero.** We find that this is indeed the case. For example

```
y.sum().backward()
```

populates `x.grad` with the gradient of `y.sum()` w.r.t. `x` which is correctly reported as

```py
# x.grad
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The x.grad is the upper triangular tensor, but I want x is upper triangular tensor too ,in your code ,x is a random tensor.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about the mathematics involved here. If you compute the gradient of `x.sum()` with respect to `x`, regardless of the value of `x` you will necessarily get a gradient of all ones (because dx/dx = 1). It doesn't matter if `x` is upper triangular or all zeros or what. As long as `x` contains all real numbers then `dx/dx = 1`.

Comment: yeah, but I just want to get the grad belong to the upper part of the upper triangular tensor.

Comment: If you just want the gradient of the upper left part then you could do `torch.triu(x.grad)` no? Which give a matrix of the gradients of loss w.r.t. and would give zero in the lower part.

Comment: maybe I can try other method in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57668368/how-to-create-torch-tensor-object-and-to-update-only-some-of-its-elements

Comment: use torch.triu(x.grad) may involve the use of opitimizer, things may be more complex. In addition, torch.triu(x.grad) may don't think the lower part of  upper triangular tensor as constants, which may cause some confuse.